# Introduction to ball tumbler chemistry?

Tags: reference-request, mechanochemistry

Chemistry that takes place in a ball tumbler is distinctly different from aqueous chemistry. Is there a good introduction to this method?

Comment: Are you referring to grinding in a "ball mill"?

Comment: @MaxW How did you guess?

Comment: Grinding isn't "chemistry"...

Comment: @MaxW But it sure is sexy: http://www.ch.cam.ac.uk/files/posters/SandersPoster_Shanghai.pdf

Comment: :-( I should have known that there would be exceptions. I really think this sort of reaction is more of a curiosity than something which would be generally applicable.